# JSF Validation gets called when the AJAX method is executed

Tags: ajax, validation, jsf, primefaces

I have a big problem with an AJAX method that gets executed from a PrimeFaces component, that also has a Validator attached. My code is this:

```
<p:spinner title="#{title}"
           id="CTRL_#{controlActual.idControl}"
           value="#{defaultValue}"
           min="#{minValue}"
           max="#{maxValue}"
           readonly="#{readOnly}"
           required="#{required}"
           requiredMessage="#{errorRequired}"
           styleClass="ewfo-spinner"
           stepFactor="0.1"
           validator="net.bizkaia.ewsf001c.validator.DecimalValidator">

    <p:ajax event="blur"
            update="@this"
            process="@this"
            listener="#{pc_Diseno.actualizarDecimales}"
            immediate="true"/>

    <f:attribute name="decimales"
                 value="#{decimals}"/>

    <f:attribute name="etiqueta"
                 value="#{controlActual.properties['label'].value.messages[idioma]}"/>
</p:spinner>
```

When the AJAX method is called, it's also called the Validator class. Is there any way to call this AJAX method without calling the Validator?

Comment: Where is the validator? Are you talking about `required=true`?

Comment: I omitted the Validator tag of the Spinner component by mistake.